# GTA 5 cannot save game

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

Every time it tells me to sign in, and I sign in but then it says sign in again so I do, and the cycle continues. So I pressed (B) and went into the game, but it won't let me save, as it says I'm not signed in.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Socialclub will go down (usually after a patch). You can check the rockstar games website to see their server status if the issue still persists.